# How to evaluate lists inside a list, which have different attributes inside (int, str, list):

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so I have a list:

```
some_lists = [
[int1, str1, list1[int, int]]
[int2, str2, list2[int, int]]
[int3, str3, list3[int, int]]
]
```

I'm trying to generate a list that contains one of the three lists listed above, by selecting the list based on `int#`

```
def get_list(some_lists: List[list], int1: int) -> list: 
"""
>>>get_list(some_lists, int1)
[int1, str1, list1[int, int]]
"""

new_list = []

for content in some_lists:
    if content.startswith(int1):
        new_list.append(content)
return new_list
```

but after I run it I get the following error:
`builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I think that `list#` is the one causing the disruption but I have no idea how to evaluate it

I'm just starting with scripts so can't use advanced functions.

Comment: `startswith()` is for strings, for a list check index `content[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` doesn't have `startswith()`, that's for `str`. use list index to get the first member in the list.

```
def get_list(some_lists: List[list], int1: int) -> list: 
    new_list = []
    for content in some_lists:
        if content[0] == int1:
            new_list.append(content)
    return new_list
```